# String not being returned

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm trying to access a parent class to pass information from it to its child and then echo that information to the page, but i cannot seem to get the `$flavor` to echo out from the `Soda` class i created. What gets echo'd out to the screen is; `Product Name: Space Juice Soda Flavor:` - obviously something is wrong with my `__construct` (i think)  in the `Soda` class but cannot figure out what.

```
class Product {

public $name = 'default_name';
public $price = 0;
public $desc = "default description";

function __construct($name, $price, $desc) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->desc = $desc;
}

public function getInfo() {
    return "Product Name: " . $this->name;
}
}

class Soda extends Product {

public $flavor;

function __construct($name, $price, $desc, $flavor) {
    parent::__construct($name, $price, $desc);
}

public function getInfo() {
    return "Product Name: " . $this->name . " Flavor: " . $this->flavor;
}
}

$shirt = new Product("Space Juice T-Shirt", 20, "Awesome Grey T-Shirt");
$soda = new Soda("Space Juice Soda", 2, "Thirst mutilator", "Grape");

echo $soda->getInfo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `flavor` in your Soda class.

```
class Soda extends Product {

       public $flavor;

       function __construct($name, $price, $desc, $flavor) {
           parent::__construct($name, $price, $desc);
           $this->flavor = $flavor; // add this line here <<<<<<<<<<<<<
       }
       ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to assign `$flavor` in your constructor

```
function __construct($name, $price, $desc, $flavor) {
    parent::__construct($name, $price, $desc);
    $this->flavor = $flavor;
}
```